# Recieve list of objects in Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter, query-string

I am receiving some filters from a data-table plugin made in React in my Spring Boot @RestController. The plugin sends the filters in this way:
filtered[0][id] = "tableColumnName"
filtered[0][value] = "tableColumnValue"

I am receiving some other pagination and relevant information on a DTO, like this:

```
@GetMapping("/search")

public ResponseEntity<DashboardDTO> search(SearchDTO searchDTO){

}
```

and my SearchDTO is something like this:

```
public class SearchDTO{
    public int pageNumber;
    public int pageSize;
    public int total;
    public int pages;
    @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
    public List<Long> ids;
    public List<FilterDTO> filters;
}
```

If I try to add, for example, a List of a FilterDTO, where FilterDTO is as follows:

```
public class SearchFilters {
    public int id;
    public String value;
}
```

then I get the following error:

```
property referenced in indexed property path is neither an array nor a list nor a map
```

The request is as follows:

```
endpoint/search?pageSize=5&pageNumber=0&filtered[0][id]=columnName1&filtered[0][value]=value1&filtered[1][id]=columnName2&filtered[1][value]=value2
```

How can I receive this kind of parameter in my controller?

Comment: Can you add a sample url with filter parameters?

Comment: Can you please add the code for `FilterDTO` and also the one corresponding to "If I try to add, for example, a List of a FilterDTO (...)"? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comments, just edited the post with the FilterDTO and the sample url. I think the problem is that parser can't recognize the id as a property in "filtered[0][id]", but it would work if it was filtered[0].id.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I couldn't get them as a parameter from the querystring but I could from the body. The problem was that the serializer used in the frontend did `filtered[0][id]` and not `filtered[0].id`, so the backend parser didn't know the id was a property.

I could get it as a body with `@RequestBody` though, but it was a `POST` request so it didn't came from the querystring.